# MySQL - Data Deletion Based on Amount and ID

Tags: mysql

Question please, I have the three tables shown below

I am trying to delete the rows in Table A that are also in table B, to arrive at data in table C.
But note that if there are 2 instances with the same amount in table A (that is in table B), only delete one of them.

I am not sure how to do this efficiently as the amounts is a DOUBLE type. 
I have considered adding the elements of table B to table A with a negative sign which is ok, since I will be eventually applying a summing on table A Grouped by ID for the final Results, but I am not sure if that is the most efficient way.

Thank you

```
CREATE TABLE A (id VARCHAR(1),
                sub_id INT,
                amount DOUBLE,
                CONSTRAINT pk_a PRIMARY KEY (id,sub_id));
CREATE TABLE B (id VARCHAR(1),
                amount DOUBLE,
                CONSTRAINT pk_b PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE C (id VARCHAR(1),
                sub_id INT,
                amount DOUBLE,
                CONSTRAINT pk_c PRIMARY KEY (id,sub_id));

INSERT INTO A 
  (id,sub_id,amount)
VALUES
  ('A',1,40),
  ('A',2,43),
  ('A',3,91),
  ('A',4,71),
  ('B',1,90),
  ('B',2,88),
  ('B',3,88),
  ('C',1,21),
  ('C',2,22);

INSERT INTO B 
  (id,amount)
VALUES
  ('A',40),
  ('B',88);

INSERT INTO C
  (id,sub_id,amount)
VALUES
  ('A',2,43),
  ('A',3,91),
  ('A',4,71),
  ('B',1,90),
  ('B',3,88),
  ('C',1,21),
  ('C',2,22);
```

Comment: Isn't there a primary key in TableA?

Comment: @Strawberry thank you didn't know about this I'll follow this and update the question

Comment: @forpas yeah there is, it's a multiple column primary key, but you can't relate Table A to Table B except on ID and Amount

Comment: It is not needed to relate to TableB but for the deletions. Also what is your version of MySql?

Comment: MYSQL  8.0.19 is my version

Comment: @Strawberry this is expected to be pasted like that?

Comment: Yes. Much better.

Comment: Please provide the desired result

Comment: But why are these DOUBLE??

Comment: The desired results is in table C and I know that for the example above it's double, because the values in the table I'm working with is a really big number that requires DOUBLE... or DECIMAL with the most number of digits possible

Comment: Fair enough then!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables with an another join to a query that returns row numbers for the rows of the table A that are duplicates for the columns id and amount.
These row numbers will be used so only 1 row of the duplicates is deleted:

```
DELETE A
FROM A
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, amount ORDER BY id, sub_id) rn
  FROM A
) r ON r.id = A.id AND r.sub_id = A.sub_id AND r.rn = 1
INNER JOIN B
ON B.ID = A.ID AND B.Amount = A.Amount
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08f33c7ac323a47572646142b2731dac).
Results:

```
> id | sub_id | amount
> :- | -----: | -----:
> A  |      2 |     43
> A  |      3 |     91
> A  |      4 |     71
> B  |      1 |     90
> B  |      3 |     88
> C  |      1 |     21
> C  |      2 |     22
```

Comment: man this is next level stuff thank you... I'll try to understand what you did but the results is as expected.